# Recreate this fluid dynamic swirl

Tags: visual, lateral-thinking

Recreate the below swirl (as close as possible), using [this](http://git.amandaghassaei.com/FluidSimulation/) visualizer, and explain your method:

[image]

Comment: This isn't an [tag:enigmatic-puzzle] - the rules are clear

Comment: I wonder what is the official way to start over in
[that awesome fluid simlulator](http://git.amandaghassaei.com/FluidSimulation/)
in a browser?
The quickest way I stumbled onto is `CTRL+F ESC`,
which begins and aborts a browser text search
but also refreshes/clears the simulator as a side effect.
(I'm still having fun trying to produce a better matching result and playing with the simulator otherwise.  Not even sure I recounted accurately how the first
approximation was obtained.)

Comment: In what way is this a puzzle? Also, questions relying on outside resources are generally disallowed.

Comment: @Deusovi, it's a puzzle in the sense that it's a game, which, BTW, the word "game" shows up pretty often in the _definition_ of puzzle.

Comment: Puzzles are not games to play or trial-and-error exercises to finally achieve a desired result.  Puzzles are a series of clues to pursue, which when combined with reasoning allow the solver to move to the final solution. This question, while interesting, is not a puzzle.  Beyond that, it requires an off-site resource; this is not a self-contained question, which in and of itself makes this posting a poor fit here.  On both counts, this is closeworthy for being off topic.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it requires an off-site resource, and because it is not an actual puzzle.

Comment: @Rubio, you go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First approximation:

[image]

Obtained by...

> ...starting at center top,
>  
>    dragging halfway down slowly, about a second,
>  
>    pausing about half a second, and
>  
>    dragging the rest of way to bottom slowly,
>                again about a second.

Took what seemed like a minute to evolve.

Comment: When I saw this question I thought - 'This looks like a humn-ish question'.